# how to convert Special characters in mule flow

Tags: mule, converters, datamapper

when I use a datamapper to convert json to xml, fields maybe contain Portuguese (ã, ô, á, é, í, etc). 
for example:
how to convert (ã, ô, á, é, í, etc) to (a, e, I, o , u, c etc)

thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `java.text.Normalizer` in a MEL expression in your mapping.

See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/text/Normalizer.html